# np.random.choice - can't specify number of coin flips

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to produce a million results of 3 bias coin flips - random.randint allows me to specify the number of flips but random.choice seems to only let me specify the size. What's I'm trying to get is:
million results of 3 flips each with 60% chance of heads on a coin.

Comment: `size` is the same as `num` in this case. It is the size of the output array (which can also be multi-dimensional).

Comment: @Graipher meaning size=(int(1e6),3) would be 1 million of 3 flips?

Comment: Well, it will be 3 million flips but output in a 2D array of shape `(1000000, 3)`, so effectively yes. Flips (or more general, random choices) are independent of each other so this distinction does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want this:

```
np.random.choice([0, 1], size = (10**6, 3), p = [.4, .6])
```

or

```
(np.random.rand(10**6, 3) < .6).astype(int)
```